# Do you know any synonyms of "gone wrong"

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a list of synonyms (ideally formal) to say that something (an endeavor) has "gone wrong". Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: [probably not foozle but one of these](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/err) or [these](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/go%20wrong). It would help if you could be more precise.

Comment: Depends on usage - in aerospace industry, RUD (rapid unscheduled/unintentional/unplanned disassembly) might be used: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/10022/who-coined-the-phrase-rapid-unscheduled-disassembly,

Answer (score 1):

As hinted at in the comments, one would need to understand clearly the context of the statement and the specific meanings of each option in the list in order to make a correct application.  Some of these terms apply to specific contexts, for example to sailors, bankers, etc., and without knowing the intended context, it is impossible to make a list of suggested equivalents.

malfunction

fail

make a mistake

develop a fault

go downhill

go south (informal)

take a turn for the worse

founder

go bankrupt

go bust

go belly up (informal)

collapse

go under

go/throw out of kilter

turn turtle (i.e. capsize)

sink

lapse

decay

deteriorate

go haywire (informal)

go crazy (informal)

go out of control

go astray

go bung (informal)

go short

go sour / sour

NOTE: These terms are **not** interchangeable; they must be correctly applied according to their context.  Nor is this meant to be, by any means, an exhaustive list.  There are likely hundreds of similar expressions for other contexts.  This is just meant to highlight some of the wide potential for possibilities--for some perspective as to the actual scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly in formal contexts, you often make negative statements by refusing to make positive ones (this is known as *litotes*). So **"this has not gone well"** is a common way of saying "this has gone badly" or "this has gone wrong."